# align content to top in div

Tags: html, css

I'm not a clever man, just trying to make a responsive page with a left sidebar, so far that's okay, but I cannot figure out how to align the content of the main div to the top.

**This is the code**: [https://jsfiddle.net/kissja74/df8vkn2a/](https://jsfiddle.net/kissja74/c6a7faun/)

```css
 #content {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
   
    #menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    background-color: blue;
    }
```

```html
 <div id='content'>
    <div id='menu'>menu</div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi interdum porttitor accumsan. Aliquam at egestas lacus, sed ultrices dui.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: All you need is float or display:inline-block; Don't use position for simple things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to your style

```
#menu {float: left}
```

Comment: thank you very much!!! i'm so old and newbie, that i'm still fighting with jsfiddle to make public my code and your answer is already here. thank you for your help!

Comment: Anytime @JánosKiss